# React - Handling Form Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started coding in React. I have a question related to handling form data. In some of the examples, the data is put in the component state:

```
this.state = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
}
```

One of my friends told me that data is not safe (all of the component state can be easily viewed with React developer tools) if I put all the form data in the component state.

I am really confused by this.

I have written below code. I have moved username and password out of the component.

```
let formFields = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

export default class LoginComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            error: {
                username: false,
                password: false
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mp-form">
                <form>
                    <div className="field-wrap">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="USERNAME" onChange={event => handleEvent.call(this, 'username', event.target.value)} />
                        <span style={{
                            display: this.state.error.username === true ? 'block' : 'none'
                        }}>Please enter UserName</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-wrap">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" onChange={event => handleEvent.call(this, 'password', event.target.value)} />
                        <span style={{
                            display: this.state.error.password === true ? 'block' : 'none'
                        }}>Please enter Password</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field-wrap">
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
                        <input type="button" value="Create" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an account yet? Register here</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function handleEvent(type, value, context) {

    if (type === 'username') {
        formFields.username = value;
    }
    else if (type === 'password') {
        formFields.password = value
    }
    console.log(type, value);
    var userNameStatus = formFields.username.length === 0 ? true : false;
    var passwordStatus = formFields.password.length === 0 ? true : false;

    this.setState({
        error: {
            username: userNameStatus,
            password: passwordStatus
        }
    });
}
```

What is the best practice for handling form data with validation?

Comment: Few resources that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122656/reactjs-form-validation-when-state-is-not-immediately-updated https://medium.com/@cubbuk/validation-with-form-inputs-in-reactjs-1f17174875f1

Comment: Since you don't determine the extensions install by your users, you would always have to assume that the `input[type=password]` can be read.. There are nothing you can do to prevent this in either react, or any other JavaScript library. That is just how the browsers works.